# Fatal Error: Silex\Application::share()

Tags: php, api, composer, symfony, silex

Eu estou desenvolvendo uma API em Silex e ao tentar testa-la no meu servidor, estou me deparando com seguinte erro:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method Silex\Application::share() in /var/www/App/Config/config.php on line 24

E a função `share` é uma função do próprio `Silex` porém não sei a razão deste erro.

A linha de código que ele está apontando é essa aqui:

```
'users' => $app->share(function($app) {
       $em = $app['orm.em'];
       return $em->getRepository('\App\Model\Entity\User');
})
```

Comment: Não há esse método implementado [aqui](https://github.com/silexphp/Silex/blob/master/src/Silex/Application.php). Tem certeza que você instalou a versão correta da biblioteca?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Então, rodei o composer require silex/silex e me retornou: Nothing to install or update

Comment: O seu problema é de versão mesmo. Você pegou esse código de uma versão e instalou outra. Veja esta pergunta relacionada no SOen: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28163693/1452488.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gostaria de pedir desculpas antecipadamente: não sou falante português, apenas estou usando o Google Translate para traduzir a minha resposta.

Como outras pessoas indicaram que você parece estar lendo a documentação para o Silex 1.x, mas o que você instalou é o Silex 2.x.

Uma das principais diferenças entre as duas versões é que o recipiente de injeção de dependência que Silex usa - Pimple - foi incorporado no próprio Silex em 1.0, enquanto que em 2.0 é tratado como uma aplicação separada (e provavelmente essa é uma boa idéia). `Share` é na verdade um método Pimple, não um método Silex.

Bem, eu digo que é um método de Pimple ... *era* um método de Pimple. No Pimple 1.x, todas as dependências eram objetos transitórios, a menos que se usasse especificamente o método `share` para torná-lo um singleton. Na versão atual do Pimple (3.x), o padrão foi alterado e todas as dependências são automaticamente singletons por padrão, então o método `share` é redundante.

O que você precisa fazer é seguir a documentação Silex 2.x e Pimple 3.x ao configurar sua aplicação.

Referências:

[(Silex 1.x / Pimple 1.x) Por padrão, cada vez que você recebe um serviço, Pimple retorna uma nova instância. Se quiser que a mesma instância seja devolvida para todas as chamadas, envolva sua função anônima com o método `share()`](https://github.com/silexphp/Pimple/tree/1.1#defining-shared-services)

[(Silex 2.x / Pimple 3.x) Por padrão, cada vez que você recebe um serviço, Pimple retorna a mesma instância.](https://pimple.symfony.com/#defining-factory-services)